# Why non-increasing is decreasing?

Tags: definition

As far as I know, by definition, ***non-decreasing*** means ***increasing*** and ***non-increasing*** means ***decreasing***. My general question is: why some people use non-increasing and non-decreasing?

In fact, it raises some confusing to me. For example, the sequence

> $1,2,3,4$

is increasing and thus the sequence

> $4,1,2,3$

is non-increasing. So, based on the definition, it is decreasing, but it is not.

Comment: What you think of as nonincreasing isn't what I think of as non-increasing.

Comment: "non-increasing means decreasing" NO : $0,0,0,\ldots$ is **non**-increasing but not decreasing.

Comment: "nonincreasing" $\neq$ "not increasing"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit of confusing terminology.

"Non-increasing," unfortunately, does not mean "not increasing" - it means "**never** increasing." So, for example, the sequence $$3,3,2,1$$ is non-increasing - $3\not<3, 3\not<2, 2\not<1$. The definition is similar for non-*de*creasing. (Note in particular that non-increasing does *not* imply decreasing, as the above example shows.)

The sequence $$4,1,2,3$$ has both increases ($2$ to $3$) and decreases ($4$ to $1$); so it is - awkwardly - not increasing, not decreasing, not non-increasing, and not non-decreasing.

**Ugh!**

Comment: To add to the confusion in France (and possibly some other countries), we consider increasing as losely increasing while in U.S it means strictly increasing (the same way we consider positive as being $\ge 0$ and in U.S $>0$). Thus for me $3,3,2,1$ **is** decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that a non-increasing sequence is different than a decreasing one in the sense that decreasing one "decreases every time" and non-increasing "doesn't increase at all" So the example you gave wouldn't be non increasing as it increases from 1 to 2 and 2 to 3.

Answer (score 0):

There are three conditions of change to the next event. Increasing, decreasing and remaining constant. Negative to these three states are non-increasing, non-decreasing and not remaining constant, i.e, varying. 
So they are not mutually exclusive.